# Network vulnerability scanner optimal positioning in network

Tags: firewalls, vulnerability-scanners

Scenario:
There is a network infrastructure with IT and OT subnets and DMZ. I can only place 2 scanners in the whole infrastructure. Are there any recommendations or best practices for how to plan the scanner placement? (maybe guides/books/handbooks on this topic?)

Where must firewalls be placed in this case and how it is possible to do external scanning?

Comment: What do you mean by "external scanning"? What's doing the scanning, what's external? And you don't place the firewalls based on the scanners. You simply configure the firewalls to protect what needs protecting and allow the scanners. This is really looking like a networking question, not a security question.

Comment: @schroeder Hi thanks for comment. in external scanning I mean doing scanning while being outside of the network. for example when external employee scans the network through Citrix gateway. 
regarding the question topic, I wanted to know what can be the best security practice of scanner placement not just simple deployment in network

Comment: If scanning through a gateway, then it's not an "external" scan. As for placement, I think you might be thinking there is more to this than there is. You place the scanner where it can reach the targets you want it to reach. This is really sounding like a networking discussion, not a security discussion.